# django forms - rendering vertical checkboxes for M2M

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I would like use vertical checkboxes for M2M. Here's a code sample:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    ...
    groups = models.ManyToManyField (
        Group,
        related_name = "contacts",
        verbose_name = _("Groups"),
    )
    ...

class Group (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField (
        unique = True,
        max_length = 100,
        db_index = True,
    )

class ContactAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact

    radio_fields = {"groups": admin.VERTICAL} # only for foreignkey or for choices
```

Any help for it?

thanks,
V.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the field in the form you could change the widget like so:

```
groups = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Group.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```